# How do I scan on a Canon MG3150?

Tags: system

I have the printer up and running, but I want to scan the image to my email address but it just seems to scan it then print it out?

Comment: Scanning an image from the printer is nothing Ubuntu is involved with. That is purely done inside the printer (my printer has wifi and uses a mail adress to directly send the scan to that address; works even w/o a PC). Unless you want to save the scan onto your system and then put it into a mail. In that case you need to select "file" instead of a "printer" when asked for the destination.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware (firmware)  issue

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar printer: check the firmware as I have to send mine back to Canon after calling their support line (they have a free support line).

**It's a hardware issue not related to Ubuntu.**  Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news!

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)